How can I resolve CVE-2023-2976 & CVE-2023-1370 vulnerabilities in Maven guava:31.1-jre & json-smart:2.4.7 while using spring-data-commons:3.3.1?
I recently discovered CVE-2023-2976 & CVE-2023-1370 vulnerabilities in my project. According to my SCA tool, these vulnerabilities stem from my use of guava:31.1-jre and json-smart:2.4.7. I could see that in my pom.xml with updated version of guava and json-smart.
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
     <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
     <version>32.1.0-jre</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
     <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
     <version>2.9.0</version>
 </dependency>

I have also checked in Jenkins Console log that it is coming from spring-data-commons(3.3.1) which is the latest version: Jenkins Console Log:
[INFO] [2024-07-15 14:53:03,518 +0000] - Start parsing pom files
[INFO] [2024-07-15 14:53:03,521 +0000] - org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:3.3.1
[INFO] [2024-07-15 14:53:03,521 +0000] - +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:6.1.9:compile
[INFO] [2024-07-15 14:53:03,522 +0000] - |  - org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:6.1.9:compile
[INFO] [2024-07-15 14:53:03,552 +0000] - +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] [2024-07-15 14:53:03,552 +0000] - |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.7:compile
[INFO] [2024-07-15 14:53:03,552 +0000] - |  |  - net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.4.7:compile

Local CLI(mvn dependency:tree):

[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.6.1:tree (default-cli) @ MyProjectName ---
[INFO] com.xxx.xxxxxx:MyProjectName:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:32.0.1-jre:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:3.33.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.18.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:2.8:compile
[INFO] +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.4.9:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:2.0.13:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:3.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:6.1.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:6.1.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:6.1.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.23.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.23.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:2.0.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.17.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.17.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.17.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:10.1.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:10.1.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:10.1.25:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:6.1.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:6.1.10:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:6.1.10:compile
[INFO] +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sqs:jar:1.12.761:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.12.761:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.16.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor:jar:2.17.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.12.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.amazonaws:jmespath-java:jar:1.12.761:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:3.3.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:3.3.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:3.3.1:test
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:4.0.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:2.1.3:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.25.3:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.14.17:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.awaitility:awaitility:jar:4.2.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.10.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.10.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.3.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.10.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.10.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.10.2:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.10.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:5.11.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.14.17:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:5.11.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:6.1.10:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.9.1:test
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.6.1:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:3.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:6.1.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:6.1.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:6.1.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:6.1.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:6.1.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:jar:4.13.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.22:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:5.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:jar:6.5.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.transaction:jakarta.transaction-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.5.3.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:6.0.6.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- io.smallrye:jandex:jar:3.1.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.7.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:4.0.5:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-core:jar:4.0.5:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.eclipse.angus:angus-activation:jar:2.0.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:4.0.5:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     \- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:4.1.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.inject:jakarta.inject-api:jar:2.0.1:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:6.1.10:compile
[INFO] +- com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:jar:12.6.3.jre8:compile
[INFO] +- com.mikesamuel:json-sanitizer:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.micrometer:micrometer-observation:jar:1.13.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-commons:jar:1.13.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-jakarta9:jar:1.13.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.13.1:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.2.2:runtime
[INFO] |        \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:runtime
[INFO] +- com.networknt:json-schema-validator:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.ethlo.time:itu:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.17.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.17.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.17.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.17.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] \- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sns:jar:1.12.753:compile

Complete pom.xml:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId> 
        <version>3.3.1</version> 
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.xxx.xx.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>app-api-dpp</artifactId>   
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> 
    <name>app-api-dpp</name>
    <description>Dashboard for My Ptoject</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version> 
        <!-- <start-class>com.xxx.xx.xxx.ProcessStageApplication</start-class>   -->
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- guava: externally defined -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>32.1.0-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- json-smart:externally defined -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
                <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- json-smart:externally defined -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
                <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add spring-data-commons dependency -->
        <!-- excluding: guava, jsonpath, json-smart-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
                <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
                        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                            <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
                                <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
            </exclusions>           
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId> 
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava-testlib</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>         
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <version>1.18.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
                <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>12.6.3.jre8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
        </dependency>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.4.2</version>
        </dependency>-->
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
                 
                    <!-- <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <configuration>
                                <mainClass>xxx.xxx.xx.xxx.ProcessStageApplication</mainClass>
                                <executable>true</executable>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>    --> 
                                
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        
    </build>
    
</project>

Initially, I included spring-data-commons version 3.3.1 in my project and excluded the vulnerable dependencies json-smart:2.4.7 and guava:31.0.1-jar. Despite this, I still encounter references to these older versions (json-smart:2.4.7 and guava:31.0.1-jar) in my Jenkins Console log. I've already upgraded to json-smart:2.4.9 and guava:32.0.1-jre in my pom.xml. Why do these older versions continue to appear, and how can I ensure that my updated dependencies are properly used throughout my project?
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

I have used following dependencies in my pom.xml: as well

spring-boot-starter (3.3.1)
spring-boot-starter-web
spring-boot-starter-test
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
spring-boot-starter-actuator


First why do you define json-path yourself and also with verison because it's already provided by spring boot (in more recent versions)... that's also true for json-smart .. Furthermore the question: Do you really require guava yourself ? Also why all those excludes? The definition of the maven-compiler-plugin is not necessary... only <java.version>17</java.version> as a property which is set by default to 17 with SB 3+
